# which version of apache poi needed for spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTFileVersion?

Tags: java, apache-poi

so i am trying to "remove" the save changes popup, which opens up upon closing the the excel file. i found this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37724642/how-to-get-rid-of-save-changes-prompt-on-xlsx-files-created-with-apache-poi-x) but now i am encountering this error:

> The type
>   org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTFileVersion
>   cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class
>   files

when calling `workBook.getCTWorkbook().addNewFileVersion();`. i have added poi-ooxml-schemas-3.15.jar as well as poi-ooxml-3.15.jar and poi-3.15.jar. Anyone has a solution for either the error, or a better way to "remove" the popup?

Comment: See https://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10025. `ooxml-schemas-1.3.jar` is needed. But what about the very simple second answer in your linked SO-Post? Will this not better suit?

Comment: its not working. i am using pivot tables (guess thats the reason for the popup)