# generate pdf from excel using java poi and edit layout

Tags: java, itext, apache-poi

I have seen that there is possibility to save excel in pdf format using POI librar: [Java Apache POI Excel save as PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26056485/java-apache-poi-excel-save-as-pdf)

My question is is it possible also to edit layout like cell size?

Comment: This is mainly a `iText` question. It is `apache poi` which reads text from the spreadsheet cells but `iText` which writes the `PDF`. So `apache poi` only can **get** the cell size, but `iText` must **set** the size of the `PdfPCell` in the `PdfPTable` then.

Comment: how to do it with itext?

Comment: What have you tried? There are `itext pdfptable example`s. Where exactly are you stuck?